# Failed to validate composer.json - registration.php not setup in autoload files directive Magento 2

Tags: magento2

As you can see from the title, whenever I submit my new module to Magento it throws the "Failed to validate composer.json - registration.php not setup in autoload files directive." message, but I cant work out why.

Here is my composer.js file contents...

```
{
  "name": "vendor/module",
  "description": "Module description here",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "GPL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~7.1.0|~7.2.0|~7.3.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "app/code/vendor/module/registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my directory structure;

```
- app
-- code
--- vendor
---- module > registration.php (this is where this file resides)
- code
- pub
```

This is the content of the regsitration.php file...

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);

require_once(BP.'/lib/internal/vendor/App/autoload.php');
```

Can anyone see/tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  Any help or advice would be very appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Think maybe this :

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
      "app/code/vendor/module/registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
```

Should be like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortuntely this doesnt work.  I believe its the file structure I need.  When I install the extension, I need a lib/internal/Vendor directory created and also a Vendor directory placed in pub/media.  So the initial module will hold app, lib and pub directories along with the composer file.  It appears I am unable to use a path to point to the registration.php file in the composer.js

Comment: ah too bad , I always use bin/magento module:enable Module_Name so never have that composer problem.  I suggest looking at some other extensions and check how they fix that issue.